# Defining multiple Include and Select over an entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following Entities for testing purposes:-

1. A blog entity
2. A blog can have multiple comments.
3. Each comment can have multiple tags.
4. And of the tags can have multiple related tags.

so i have defined the following to retrieve all the related information regarding a Blog:-

```
var blog = entities.Blogs.Include(v=>v.comments.Select(a =>a.tags));
```

But how i can retrieved the "related tags" for a Blog ? as i am only able to define one Include and one Select for each entity.
thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do that? How do you want to use the query?

Comment: Could you please show us the structure of your tables, especially relation between tags and related tags and model that should be filled by your query?

Comment: i need to retrived all the related information when the Blod ID is passed to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is the structure of your database and how looks like blog class, so I just imagened simple db structure for you requirements and retrive data into anonymous objects:

```
var blogID = 1;
var blog = entities.Blogs.Where(b=>b.ID == blogID).Select(b=> new {
   BlogID = b.BlogID,
   Comments = b.Comments.Select(c=>new {
       CommentID = c.CommentID,
       Tags = c.Tags.Select(t=>new {
           TagID = t.TagID,
           Name = t.Name,
           RelatedTags = t.Tags1.Select(tg => new {
              TagID = tg.TagID,
              Name = tg.Name
           })
       })
   })
})
```

The `.Include()` operator is useful when you need to load some additional data eagerly in data context. For example:

```
var blog = var blog = entities.Blogs.Include("Comments").FirstOrDefault(b=>b.ID == blogID); //Query is executing here and getting also comments related to the blog
//then you can go through comment without any additional queries:
foreach(var comment in blog.Comments)
{
   //no queries executed here
}
```

EDIT:
Yes it's possible. If you're using DbContextAPI you need to do something like this:

```
//here is tags1 is navigation property for related tags
var blog = entities.Blogs.Include(v=>v.comments.Select(a =>a.tags.Select(t=>t.tags1))); 
//Or with ObjectContext .Include() method:
//here is tags1 is navigation property for related tags
var blog1 = entities.Blogs.Include("comments.tags.tags1").FirstOrDefault(b=>b.BlogID = blogID);
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply; but for the second approach ; how i can retrieve the comment tags and related tags? as it is not possible to define multiple >Include on the same query. and why you are only selecting the first comment only for each Blog?

Comment: You are mistaken in believing that you can only include one Include on the same query.  You can have as many as you need.

Answer (score 1):

There is no limitation to the number of Includes you can have on an Entity, and you can use SelectMany or subselects to select the related tags.

```
var blog = entities.Blogs.Include(v=>v.comments.Select(a =>a.tags.Select(t=>t.relatedtags));
```